# Laravel API unauthorised errors only on production

Tags: node.js, laravel, ssl, axios, laravel-api

I've got an external app that sends requests to my Laravel API with the machine to machine authentication set up. For some reason the system works on my dev environment but as soon as i go to production the requests get returned with 401 errors.

The external app carries an authentication token which it gets from my Laravel app before every request so it should be authenticated correctly

For reference, here is the `.htaccess` file I use in case something is wrong with it.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

This is the code I use in my external app to get the token from my API, I know this code works as I can see a valid token generated in subsequent requests

```
async function getToken() {
    var data = {
        'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
        'client_id': process.env.CLIENT_ID,
        'client_secret': process.env.CLIENT_SECRET
    };
    const token = await axios.post(`${process.env.REQUEST_URL}oauth/token`, data)
    .then(function(response) {
        return response.data['access_token'];
    });
    return token;
}
```

Comment: `401 errors` it laravel error it nothing with server config so check in your request header it should pass vaid token  and if not working then generate token in production and use that

Comment: @KamleshPaul the request header is passing a valid token which is why I am confused, I'm thinking its an error with my server config as it works on my dev environment but not on production

Comment: dev and production have different env so both will have there own token you cannot use dev token in prod

Comment: I'm not using my dev token on prod? As said the api sends a request to laravels oauth to get a new token every request

Comment: @KamleshPaul the token is generated by sending a post request to /oauth/token with a client ID and secret, generated by laravel, thats then used in the requests